# Matlab convn in openCV

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv

I holpe you can help me.
I'm currently translating some matlab code to c++ with opencv, but it's not working...

Now I'm not sure, if its due to my wrong translation or if I missed someting.

Matlab:

```
R=rmin:rmax;
count=size(R,2);
for k=1:count
    [L(k)]=lineint(I,C,R(k),n,part);
    if L(k)==0
        L(k)=[];
        break;
    end
end

D=diff(L);
D=[0 D];

if strcmp(sigma,'inf')==1
    f=ones(1,7)/7;
else
    f=fspecial('gaussian',[1,5],sigma);
end

blur=convn(D,f,'same');%Smooths the D vecor by 1-D convolution 
blur=abs(blur);
[b,i]=max(blur);
r=R(i);
b=blur(i);
```

OpenCV:

```
std::vector<double> L;
std::vector<int> radii;
std::vector<void*> result;
cv::Mat blur;
cv::Mat kernel;

for (int i = rmin; i <= rmax; i++) {
    double tmp = lineint(I, C, i, n, part);
    if (tmp != 0) {
        L.push_back(tmp);
        radii.push_back(i);
    }
    else
        break;
}

std::vector<double> D;
D.push_back(0);
for (int i = 1; i < L.size(); i++) {
    double tmp = L.at(i-1) - L.at(i);
    D.push_back(tmp >= 0 ? tmp : -1 * tmp);
}

//inf case
if (sigma < -1) {
    kernel = cv::Mat::ones(Size(1, 7), CV_32FC1) / 7;
}
else {
    kernel = cv::getGaussianKernel(5, sigma, CV_32FC1);
}

//flip vertical and horizontal
//rearange anchor
//http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html#filter2d
cv::flip(kernel, kernel, -1);
cv::Point anchor = cv::Point(-1, -1);
anchor = cv::Point(kernel.cols - anchor.x - 1, kernel.rows - anchor.y - 1);
cout << anchor << "|" << kernel << endl;
cv::filter2D(D, blur, -1, kernel, anchor, 0.0f, BORDER_DEFAULT);
blur = cv::abs(blur);

double min, max;
cv::Point min_loc, max_loc;
cv::minMaxLoc(blur, &min, &max, &min_loc, &max_loc);
int radius = (rmin + max_loc.y);

result.push_back(&max);
result.push_back(&radius);
```

Thanks!

**Edit**:
Sorry missed the error message:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (anchor.inside(Rect(0, 0, ksize.width,    ksize.height))) in cv::normalizeAnchor, file c:\builds\master_packslave-win64-vc12-shared\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\filterengine.hpp, line 363
```

It happens when I apply the filter at filter2D

**Edit2**:
It works if I remove the convolution update (remove the flip and the rearrangement of the anchor)

Comment: What's the problem? Show mistake message

Comment: What is not working? Can you please give a specific error message you are seeing?

Comment: Sorry forgot to add the message, updated my post

Comment: Can't you just leave the `anchor` to (-1,-1), i.e. the kernel center?

Comment: To be honest, I don't know. I just follow the openCV documentation which says: "The function does actually compute correlation, not the convolution. That is, the kernel is not mirrored around the anchor point. If you need a real convolution, flip the kernel using flip() and set the new anchor to (kernel.cols - anchor.x - 1, kernel.rows - anchor.y - 1) ."

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think I fixed it (actually the error is gone, I'm not sure if the results are the same)

I used the function provided here: http://blog.timmlinder.com/2011/07/opencv-equivalent-to-matlabs-conv2-function/

```
void conv2(cv::Mat &img, cv::Mat& kernel, int type, cv::Mat& dest) {
    cv::Mat source = img;
    if (CONVOLUTION_FULL == type) {
        source = cv::Mat();
        const int additionalRows = kernel.rows - 1, additionalCols = kernel.cols - 1;
        cv::copyMakeBorder(img, source, (additionalRows + 1) / 2, additionalRows / 2, (additionalCols + 1) / 2, additionalCols / 2, BORDER_CONSTANT, Scalar(0));
    }

    cv::Point anchor(kernel.cols - kernel.cols / 2 - 1, kernel.rows - kernel.rows / 2 - 1);
    int borderMode = BORDER_CONSTANT;
    cv::flip(kernel, kernel, -1);
    cv::filter2D(source, dest, img.depth(), kernel , anchor, 0, borderMode);

    if (CONVOLUTION_VALID == type) {
        dest = dest.colRange((kernel.cols - 1) / 2, dest.cols - kernel.cols / 2)
        .rowRange((kernel.rows - 1) / 2, dest.rows - kernel.rows / 2);
    }
}
```

He basicly aligns the anchor in a different way. I'll see if the results are sufficient